# Chromecast and HDMI-CEC events

Tags: events, chromecast, hdmi

I'm wondering how to get the play/pause event in receiver from HDMI-CEC.

From this question: [How to listen for HDMI-CEC media controls events in receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175638/how-to-listen-for-hdmi-cec-media-controls-events-in-receiver) , it seems if use mediaManager in receiver, nothing needs to be done, but I'm not using it. So I need to listen for those events myself. Can't find any documentation...

Answer (score 1):

If yo are not using MediaManager, you will not be able to receive those events; there is no event to register for outside of the commands that are called on the MediaManager and that is one of the reasons we strongly recommend to use that.

Comment: Ali any plans to add this functionality for those using their own communication channel with a custom receiver? We can't use the MediaManager because of the way our video player works. Thanks!